# Logo Image from Parent site in Sitecollection

Tags: 2007

I need your expert advise on a task I would like achieve, we have one site collection with different sites/subsites. Lets say I have a top level site "XYZ" and under that I have a site "ABC", and under the "ABC" site I have more subsites. The site and subsites has an Image-library to store images. We have an Image-library in the "ABC" site that we would like to display in all subsites under it, but not other sites/subsites under different trees (E.q site "DEF".

Please advise

Thanks 
Ronak

Comment: Thanks Robert i am new to StackExchage i did accept some of the answer.Thanks for advise

Answer (score 2):

Edit the Master page for the ABC site to reference the logo image you need, set all child sites of the ABC site to inherit the mastermage.

Comment: Thanks GavinB but they don't want to use separate master page for each parent Subsite.Thats what i suggest too.Currently we have header.htm where designer can manage html for header and this logo image coming from that file which has src attribute something like this /path/.img and so it does not work for subsite.i know this is weird approch but they dont want in masterPage so designer can manage it without sharepoint resources.Thanks